# Simple HTML DOM - Child Selectors (CSS)

Tags: php, css, simple-html-dom

I am trying to select a (direct) child of parents `div.element` using the `>` combinator, but it's failing.

HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <p>test</p>
</div>

<div class="element">
    <div class="selected">
        <p>test2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$html->find('div.element > p', 0);
```

I am looking to select the direct `p` element.

If it's a nested descendant - it shouldn't return anything, but it returns `test2`.

How can I write it to return `test`, but not `test2`? Thanks

**UPDATE:** The general consensus here on SO seems to be that Simple HTML DOM is bad. I ended up writing my code using PHP's `DOMDocument` as suggested by Phil. I did test out nevermind's solution and it did work as well. Thanks for all the help and **Happy Coding**

Comment: try to delete the angle bracket

Comment: **test2** is returned either way. `>` seems to do nothing

Comment: Try this: $html->find(div.element > p);

Comment: @aldrin27 that at least changed behavior. On the second element, it seems to return an empty string. I though it returned null if the element wasn't found. Also, specifying element index in the find call makes it look deeper?

Comment: SimpleHTMLDom is a truly terrible library and I doubt it supports the immediate child selector. See this page for a list of **much better** alternatives ~ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: @Phil I would love to just drop this thing and move on to another but it is not up to me and there already is a lot of code written using this. My only option is to try and work with what I have already.

Comment: FYI, this XPath expression will yield the result you're after ~ `//div[@class = 'element']/p`

Comment: @khuderm you can use something else for this task (I recommend the built-in Dom extension). It doesn't mean you need to drop SimpleHTMLDom or refactor any other code

Comment: @Phil You are right. I wasted too much time trying to make this work. I wrote only this part using php `DOMDocument` and that was like a breeze. If you wanna make your comment an answer, I will accept it. I try to stay away from xpath, personally. They tend to break easily with the smallest structure change.

Comment: For a simple html dom replacement with full css support [try this](https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/advanced_html_dom). Yes simple html dom is bad but it's also a very old library and for a while it was all we had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this should (must, actually:)) work (tested on 4 divs):

```
foreach($html->find('div.element') as $element) {


$paragraph=$element->find('p',0);

    if($paragraph==$element->first_child())
    echo $paragraph;

}
```

Comment: I did test out your code after I found my solution. Not sure why you deleted your answer in the first place lol. I ended up doing what @Phil suggested. If he doesn't write an answer, I will choose your as a solution since it works as well. Thanks

Comment: Np, first solution didn't worked for two <p> adjacent tags (if it is possible in your HTML structure) - IF you just want first... :)

Comment: That would have worked in my case. The first element with just the span is sometimes there and sometimes not. If it was there, I needed the value inside it only. If it didn't I wanted the value from the second element. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!